# Game center login  lock in landscape only in i OS 6

Tags: iphone, game-center, uiinterfaceorientation, ios6

When Game center is loaded its default orientation is portrait. 
 In order to lock it in landscape mode, added a category.

```
@implementation GKMatchmakerViewController (LandscapeOnly)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{ 
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

It is working fine in below iOS 6 .But in iOS6 it shows an error.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Please explain a solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

At last i avoided crash by following the workaround mentioned in Apple's iOS 6 [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html).

Workaround:

**`1.Apps should provide the delegate method`** **`application:supportedIntefaceOrientationsForWindow and ensure that portrait is one of the returned mask values.`**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

**2. When a UIBNavigationController (or a UIViewController) is involved, subclass the UINavigationController/UIViewController and overriding supportedInterfaceOrientations.**

```
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
```

And

**`In buid summary supported orientations selected landscape right and landscape left.`**

Now game center is working properly without crash.

Comment: Worked for me too, but in my case I wasn't using a UIBNavigationController but a UIViewController (its subclass), yet I still had to add method number 2 into it. You might want to replace UIBNavigationController with UIViewController in this answer.

Comment: I added that information. Your answer is now more accurate than Apple's release notes. ;)

Comment: it works but my app now supports portrait, how will I stop it from going to portrait. PLease help :(

Comment: Just a small comment: it's more elegant to include just a category attaching to NavigationController class in the Appdelegate then making a new subclass, but it's a working solution in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Have to add 1 little thing. Struggling with that stupid issue about 2 days. If above doesn't help and you have UINavigationController invovled (and you already did subclass it) you need the following (in appDelegate):

```
[window setRootViewController:navigationController]; // use this
// instead of [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

thanx 2 http://grembe.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/here-is-what-i/