# Stop MCBrowserViewController rotating. Ignores plist & won't subclass

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, orientation, multipeer-connectivity

I want the multiplayer connectivity peer picker view to launch & stay in landscape like everything else in the app.

The plist has "**Supported interface orientations**" containing just "**landscape** (right home button)", but the `MCBrowserViewController` ignores it.

I tried to subclass to `override supportedInterfaceOrientations`, but according to this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8448), it doesn't support this. `presentViewController`, which works on `MCBrowserViewController`, gives:

```
uncaughtExceptionHandler; NSInternalInconsistencyException: Could not load NIB in bundle:
            'NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/B2B62F00-15A1-4063-89B0-52EB7F3E464C/
            Parsec.app> (loaded)' with name 'MCBrowserViewController'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this behavior in the iOS 11.2 simulator. I have the `MCBrowserViewController` locked to landscape right.

Comment: [My test application](https://github.com/allenhumphreys/MCBrowserViewControllerSOTest)

Comment: @AllenHumphreys thanks, this will hopefully be helpful. If you write it into an answer in the next few hours I'll award you the bounty (assuming no-one gives the actual solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a very basic sample application and tested it using iOS 11.2. It seems that, for me, `MCBrowserViewController` is obeying the app level orientation restrictions.

You should check that your app delegate is not overriding the plist orientation values by providing an implementation of [`application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623107-application). Or, if you have a custom subclass of `UIApplication`, make sure it is not overriding [`supportedInterfaceOrientations(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623091-supportedinterfaceorientations).

I'm including the full source here:

#### ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textField: UITextField?
    let id = MCPeerID(displayName: "testpeer")
    lazy var session = MCSession(peer: id)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 0, height: 0))
        button.setTitle("Browse", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showBrowser), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.sizeToFit()
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func showBrowser() {
        let controller = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "test", session: session)
        present(controller, animated: true)
        controller.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

#### AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        return true
    }
}
```

#### Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Your extra check was spot on. I had a supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow method in the app delegate returning UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown. It was needed to fix a Game Center crash bug back in iOS6 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488838), but I had every other view controller returning UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight so I didn't notice it.