# Having issue with Game Center in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios6, game-center

I used to use this code in order to login users account in game center :

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
         if (error != nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"LOGIN");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"CANT LOGIN");
         }
     }];
```

this code works fine with iOS 5.x but crashes in iOS 6 , I would be grateful if you help to fix it.

thanks

Comment: This method is deprecated in iOS 6; set the `authenticateHandler` property instead.  (This probably won't fix your crash though.  For that you need to show more code.)

Comment: this is my code for login in GameCenter!(up) , can you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for iOS5 or 6. iOS6 changed the authentication function

iOS6

```
   localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
    {
        //Something
    }
```

iOS5

```
    [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
    {
        //Something
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in iOS 6:

```
        GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
        if (viewController != nil) {
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
            // do post-authentication work
        } else {
            // do unauthenticated work, such as error message, etc
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the [Game Center Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html)

This is how you must authenticate users in iOS6:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
         if (viewController != nil)
         {
             [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController
         }
         else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
         {
             [self authenticatedPlayer: localPlayer];
         }
         else
         {
             [self disableGameCenter];
         }
     }];
}
```

You should also checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427979/gamecenter-authentication-in-landscape-only-app-throws-uiapplicationinvalidinter), because your app might be crashing due to autorotation issues and game center, not the authentication mechanism itself

Comment: thanks a lot Lio , this code work at iOS 5 and iOS 6 together? my game work very good on iOS 5. i want my game work at iOS 5 and iOS 6 together! please help me.i have force majeure work. thx a lot.

Comment: see this error : http://1.3.3.img98.net/out.php/i474324_screen-shot-2012-09-27-at18-pm.png

Comment: Those errors are because the code I pasted is sample code, you actually have to implement those methods. And to answer your previous method, no, the code will only work in iOS6. I am using the old iOS5 code in iOS6 and it still works alright. You should track the crash down and find out, the reason. I recommend that you look into that question I linked in my answer. Good luck

Comment: This is copy / pasted from Apple's Game Center Programming guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW17 , which itself contains an error.