# Adding helpshift to an application caused UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exception, orientation

I have recently been trying to play with helpshift however I have found that it is causing an exception.

The exception is saying that I have autorotate returning yes however I am not implementing this method in any of my code and from my understanding this means it is set to NO.

If I add the different orientations to my app it automatically sets it to landscape when my iphone is not positioned in landscape.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported
>   orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x36b0d3e7 0x33545963 0x36b0d307 0x37922857 0x37ac6f21 0x37964c8b 0x37a88f73 0x37912761 0x378bacef
>   0x378ba77d 0x378ba1bf 0x30d9f5f7 0x30d9f227 0x36ae23e7 0x36ae238b
>   0x36ae120f 0x36a5423d 0x36a540c9 0x37911445 0x3790e291 0x79d95
>   0x79d30) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

As well as the helpshift API I also was required to add the following frameworks:

- CoreGraphics
- QuartzCore (already added and works)
- SystemConfiguration (already added and works)
- MobileCoreServices
- OpenGLES
- CoreTelephony
- Security
- Foundation

Without helpshift being included the app works as expected. Would any of the above frameworks cause the issue of there any issue with helpshift I should be combating? is it possible a setting is incorrect? Due to helpshift being such a new product the help is not quite there yet

Comment: Hey Peter, can you provide some more context about the problem? Are you using GameCenter in your app? It has been seen that people who are using GameCenter, iAds, etc. have faced similar issues. The Helpshift SDK should not cause such a problem on its own.

There are some [closely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427979/gamecenter-authentication-in-landscape-only-app-throws-uiapplicationinvalidinter) [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul) problems that might help.

Comment: Also, you can email us directly at support [at] helpshift.com and we'll help you resolve this problem and any other questions you might have.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response and sorry for the delay. I will email it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this same problem with the Helpshift SDK. It worked fine with version 1.3.1 but as soon as I upgraded to 1.3.4, my app stopped running with the UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation error. No other changes except the Helpshift upgrade, and I've confirmed it by downgrading to 1.3.1 (app works again) and then upgrading again to 1.3.4 (app crashes again). I can get my app to run by adding the following to the application delegate:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Using `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` results in the crash. Since I need my app to stay in portrait orientation, I added the following to my UITabBarController subclass:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
     return NO;
}
```

Comment: interesting. I do see 1 of the updates I believe for 1.3.4 was to add support for landscape so maybe something is not quite right. Helpshift have messaged me on here and on twitter which is good. Going to try as you say and follow up with helpshift as well to make sure it is a helpshift issue and to ee if it can get resolved for future :)

Comment: Just to update this did in fact resolve my issue. I will report back to helpshift to see if this might be caused by an error

Answer (score 1):

That exception means the set of orientations returned by -supportedInterfaceOrientations of the root view controller, intersected with the supported interface orientations defined in your Info.plist, produces the empty set.

Comment: Hi Dex thanks for the response. This was 1 of the things I checked and I made sure that the orientation I wanted was setup. Since your reply someone else has posted similar issues. Helpshift have also responded so looking good at getting a resolution.